# Optional parameters in ABAP CDS views?

Tags: view, cds

I'm trying to create a CDS view for consumption with optional parameters. But at the moment, optional parameters are not supported.

Is there a workaround available to somehow choose which where clauses are to be executed/used based on input parameters ?

Answer (score 3):

Did you check the **Consumption.defaultValue** annotation
Please have a look at [reference document](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cc0c305d2fab47bd808adcad3ca7ee9d/7.5.6/en-US/d60c0bf6798a481fb7412bc89934cb8a.html)

Answer (score 3):

I just put more complete answer than proposed by Dzhengo.
You can use [parameter annotations](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abencds_f1_parameter_annotations.htm) for some of the parameters which can be filled implicitly by ABAP environmental values. Annotations can be specified by keyword `@Environment.systemField` before or after the parameter and should be followeed by env field after the colon. Here is the list of possible environmental fields:

1. `#CLIENT:`
   sy-mandt
2. `#SYSTEM_DATE:`
   sy-datum
3. `#SYSTEM_TIME:`
   sy-uzeit
4. `#SYSTEM_LANGUAGE:`
   sy-langu
5. `#USER:`
   sy-uname

Sample code for defining the view:

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZVW_MARA' 
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED 
define view zvw_mara
  with parameters  
    p_matnr : matnr, 
    @Environment.systemField : #SYSTEM_DATE 
    p_datum : syst_datum, 
    p_uname : syst_uname @<Environment.systemField : #USER 
  as select from 
    mara
    { 
      key mara.matnr,  
          mara.ernam, 
          mara.ersda 
    } 
    where 
        matnr = :p_matnr 
    and ernam = :p_uname
    and ersda = :p_datum;
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment the following are the only parameters you can use as optional.

```
p_date : sydatum
@<Environment.systemField:#SYSTEM_DATE 
, p_language : spras 
@<Environment.systemField:#SYSTEM_LANGUAGE
```

Comment: these are not the only parameters any more, but I vote is locked