# Calculate previous day in ABAP CDS?

Tags: date, abap, cds

I am starting with ABAP, I use the following instruction to obtain the date in the system but I can't get the date of the previous day, does anyone have any suggestions? THANKS.

I tried with:

```
 { 
  $session.system_date as today,
  $session.system_date - 1 as yesterday
 }
```

but I can't do arithmetic operations with dates and it marks an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DATS_ADD_DAYS`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abencds_f1_date_functions.htm#!ABAP_VARIANT_3@3@) function for this task.

It does not allow putting session vars directly as an argument, but we can do the following trick:

```
define view Z_TODAY
  as select from 
    zsomething
    { 
      key field1 as type1,
      key field2 as type2,
          ...
          $session.system_date as today,
          DATS_ADD_DAYS( cast( $session.system_date as abap.dats ),-1,'NULL') as yesterday
    }
```

Wrapping the system date into `CAST` does the thing.

Another, less intuitive way (which can be more flexible sometimes) is putting [optional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39115637/optional-parameters-in-abap-cds-views/57385437#57385437) with predefined value:

```
define view Z_TODAY
with parameters  
  @Environment.systemField : #SYSTEM_DATE 
  p_datum : abap.dats
  as select from zsomething
    { 
      key field1 as type1,
      key field2 as type2,
          ...
          $session.system_date as today,
          DATS_ADD_DAYS( :p_datum,-1,'NULL') as yesterday
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand system field parameters correctly, but your second code snippet doesn't appear to make any use of the p_datum parameter you created.

Comment: @Philipp, was a typo, corrected. Thanks!