# Get current user on ABAP CDS 7.40?

Tags: abap, cds

I am working on ABAP CDS on ABAP 740 where I don't have access to the $session variables.

The case

```
USR05.bname = 'XXXXXX' where by the xxxxxx is my user id (Hard coded )
```

What is the workaround?

Comment: Hey, checkout parameter annotations and this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39115637/optional-parameters-in-abap-cds-views

Comment: @Eray this is exactly the thing he is speaking about. Those $session annotations are not available on ABAP 7.40

Comment: @Suncatcher yep you are right. I confused 7.50 and 7.40 versions. Some session annotations are not available also 7.50 version( like $session.system_date) but it's not related with this topic. Thanks for the warning :)